# Delete individual call log

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, call-history

In Gingerbread and before, long-click on an individual call log gave you also the option to delete it.

Now, in ICS, while in the Call log tab, on long-press:

- *on contact image(red):* it opens the Contact details;
- *on the cal log details(yellow):* nothing happen;
- *on the phone image(blue)*: re-dial

Now, I've found the **`Clear call log`** option in menu, but can someone confirm if it has more options and will let me choose the entry to clear, or it'll just delete my entire call log?

I've also found a lot of new **`Settings`**, but nothing about deleting an individual call log entry.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you touch an individual item in the call log, and press the Menu (vertical ellipsis) you'll see a "clear from call log" option.

Comment: I just checked this and it appears to be the only way to remove an individual item from the call log.

Comment: Still can't remove from frequently called tho :-(

Answer (score 2):

On Nexus S, touch the call log detail (yellow in OP image) to bring up contact log. Press Menu button to get "Remove from call log" option.

Answer (score 1):

Press on the "Contact image" on the left to bring up the contact. Press vertical dots in the top right corner to get "Remove from call log" (removes all log entries for this contact).

Comment: I don't know that device are you using, but on my Nexus S with ICS 4.0.3, there are no dots in the top, and if you were talking about the Menu button, there is no option available while in the contact view.

Answer (score 1):

Go in that particular contact-->press 'Menu button'-->select 'History'

You will see all the calls to that particular contact.

Press Menu-->select 'Delete'